# Is it not possible to call the in-built function e.g. svd in a custom python function that is parallized using @njit?

Tags: numpy, parallel-processing, matrix-multiplication, svd, numba-pro

The following error is obtained while trying to run my for loop involving a svd function

```
TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Untyped global name 'svd': cannot determine Numba type of <class 'function'>
```

The code is as given below.

```
from scipy.linalg import svd
import numpy as np
from numba import jit

PatchSize = 5
@jit(nopython=True)
def svd_solver(image):
  Hight = image.shape[0]
  Width = image.shape[1]
  for i in range(PatchSize):
    for j in range(PatchSize):
       Count    =  Count+1
       Patch  =  ImgInput[i:Hight-PatchSize+i+1,j:Width-PatchSize+j+1]
       SG_S, SG_V, SG_D  =  svd(Patch)
  return SG_V
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the time of writing, Scipy is not in the list of the officially supported modules in Numba (see the documentation [here](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.50.0/reference/pysupported.html) and [there](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.50.0/reference/numpysupported.html)).

However, `numpy.linalg.svd` is supported [according to the documentation](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.50.0/reference/numpysupported.html#functions) (not that it may differ from `scipy.linalg.svd`). This support is partial as "only the 2 first arguments" are supported. This should be fine in your case.

Comment: Thank you.  I use the following command to successfully run it using numba.                     
  `s,v,d = np.linalg.svd(a, full_matrices=False)`